# How can I automate phantomjs and casperjs tests in Karma

Tags: testing, rspec, phantomjs, automated-tests, casperjs

I am trying to find a way to automate tests written in phantomjs &&/|| Casperjs with karma. Apparently you can run tests in phantomjs, but you cannot use phantomjs or casper as a framework/plugin like Jasmine. I know phantomjs in not a framework, but you can write tests with it. It is a bit confusing.

What I want to achieve is basically what you can do in Rails when you run Rspec. Is it possible? Am I using the wrong tools ?

Thanks!

Comment: You use casperjs **with** phantomjs. They are not the same kind of tool. Karma is a testing suite mainly for unit testing code, casper is a tool for end-to-end testing (clicking buttons and the like), and phantom js is a headless web browser.

Comment: Thank you evolutionxbox. Ok, I am a bit confused. You can run test in phantomjs directly with phantomjs test.js and same thing in casperjs. So let's say I have a bunch of tests either in phantomjs or casperjs, how do I automate them ? I thought I could use karma since it uses phantoms as a browser, but it doesn't work, it returns an error for 'require' or 'Can't find variable: phantom', so basically it seems that it is not using phantomjs to run the test. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You can run tests directly in phantomjs. Casperjs needs phantomjs (or slimerjs) to run. Caspejs can be automated. You can easily use a task runner like grunt or gulp to automate the tests. Use either Casper or karma (not sure why you would). I'd suggest using a task runner to run Casper tests which uses phantomjs.

Comment: Why the silence? --- Check these slides http://slides.com/justinklemm/phantomjs-casperjs-other-automated-testing-tools they may help you understand.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I decided to use [mocha-casperjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-casperjs) instead which combine the power of casperjs' automation with Mocha's robust testing framework features.